# Overriding The SSIS Connection Manager ConnectionString During Run-Time

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package that I execute several times in parallel from different SQL Server Agent Jobs. I set the ConnectionString to the Connection Manager by using the command line parameter /CONNECTION.

It seems that the SSIS is overriding my run-time ConnectionString again with the design-time value. I also found an MSDN article stating that this is indeed what happens.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500430(v=sql.105).aspx

Is there a way to override the Connection Manager ConnectionString during run-time? I need this functionality because I'm using the same packages for different setups so I cannot "hard-code" the ConnectionString.

Comment: Are you also using a configuration (xml, table, environment variable, registry) to set the same connection string?

Comment: No, I'm using PackageConfigurations from SQL Server but I'm not touching that Connection Manager at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are limited to use command line only, then use **/SET** to change a value of a **variable** at runtime and using expressions, build your connection string from that variable (as the link you posted above says /SET overrides design-time value, whereas /CONNECTION doesn't.)

```
dtexec /f mypackage.dtsx /set \package.variables[myvariable].Value;myvalue
```

The other way to override or provide a **ConnectionSting** during runtime is to start usinng **Package Configurations** as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141682%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work. If you look at the link I provided, it says that it has no effect since the value is overwritten with design-time values after applying the run-time value. I'm already using Package Configurations from SQL Server but to be able to load the configurations, I need a connection to the SQL Server and that I was planning to provide with run-time parameter.

Comment: It has no effect if you are changing the **location**, but has the desired effect on the **property** ( row 3 in the table you are referring to )

Comment: You are referring to 2005 (first column). I have 2012 so the behavior is the same than in 2008 (second column) which is that it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: In SQL Server 2008 Integration Services, events occur in the following order:

The utility first applies the design-time configurations.

The utility then applies the run-time options that you specified on the command line when you started the utility.

Finally, the utility reloads and reapplies the design-time configurations.

**Because the events occur in this order, you can dynamically redirect a configuration by using the /SET command-line option to change the configuration string.**

Comment: It seems that this approach works now that I understood what you were after!

Answer (score 1):

Edit the `[mypackage].dtsx` using Notepad, manually change the `ConnectionString`, and save.